# why there is need to create a React app from scratch with Webpack and Babel if create-react-app automatically adds them?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, es6-modules

why there is need to create a React app from scratch with Webpack and Babel if create-react-app automatically adds them? I am kind of new to this thing could someone please help me to understand this thing

Comment: Creating things from scratch is a great way to learn more about how things work. CRA is a tool-kit that some very clever folks who build a lot of websites put together so they don't have to redo the same work each time! It's what is called a "boilerplate" - which is an empty box with some prepackaged stuff that are used frequently. :)

Comment: For example, you may want to use Parcel.js instead of Webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some people might not want the setup that create-react-app provides.

There are many different ways to set up a project, you can do it from scratch, by using someone elses's template, or using a CLI tool like `create-react-app`.

The choice is yours, but the recommendation for beginners is to just use CRA as it is the simplest and gets everything working together nicely for you to just get building!